# Criar array ao passar valores pelo POST PHP

Tags: php, array

Não consegui localizar nada semelhante no forum, não sei se usei as palavras corretas, mas estou com o seguinte problema.

Estou enviando uma sequencia numerica por formulario method POST e depois pego o valor e tento tranformar em array, porém o retorno fica assim:

```
Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4,5,6 )
```

eu preciso que fique assim:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 )
```

Meu código está nesta forma:

```
<?php
$sorteados2 = $_POST['sorteados2'];
$arr2 = array($sorteados2);
print_r($arr2);
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="sorteados2" value="1,2,3,4,5,6">
    <button type="submit">Sortear</button>
</form>
```

Preciso que cada número fique definido separadamente dentro do array, e não agrupados em apeas um.

Existe outra forma de fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Seu campo `hidden` está enviando uma string com o conteúdo "**1,2,3,4,5,6**".

Em PHP existe a função [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) que transforma uma string em um array, utilizando outra string como separador.

A função espera 3 parâmetros:

1. O delimitador que será usado como separador de cada item do *array*
2. A *string* que será convertida
3. Opcionalmente um inteiro indicando o limite máximo para o tamanho do *array*. Nesse caso, os "pedaços" que poderiam ser elementos do *array* ficarão na última posição, como uma substring.

```php
$array_sorteados = explode(',', $sorteados2);
```

Irá retornar:

```
Array([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6)
```

E, caso use o limitador (no caso 3)...

```php
$array_sorteados = explode(',', $sorteados2);
```

... irá retornar:

```
Array([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [3,4,5,6])
```

Aconselho a ler a documentação da função, pois existem outros detalhes que não foram mencionados.

Comment: Realmente a informação estava sendo enviada como se fosse apenas uma variavel e o explode com delimitador ao capiturar a informação novamente resolveu meu problema ao recriar o array separando os números corretamente. Obrigado Marcos.

Comment: Disponha estamos aqui para ajudar.

Comment: No caso de resolver o problema, lembre-se sempre de aceitar a resposta.